# exec: "gcc": executable file not found in %PATH%

Tags: go, gcc, go-ethereum

I'm trying to start writing code in Golang. Whenever I try to run my code or build it I get the following error.

## github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/crypto/secp256k1

cgo: C compiler "gcc" not found: exec: "gcc": executable file not found in %PATH%

I'm using windows so I followed some steps from a previous problem and installed TDM-GCC. Inside the files in the bin folder there is a gcc.exe file that should be fixing my issue.

In my path variables and also my system variables I've added C:\TDM-GCC-64\bin and I'm still getting the error. I've also restarted my pc to make sure the environment variables were updated.

Anyone have any idea how I could fix this?

Comment: If your system variables are correct, then when you try to call `gcc` from the console, it should find it. Did you try that?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it's asking for the gcc to be installed. Try install GCC by downloading and installing it from (https://gcc.gnu.org/install/index.html) . Once GCC is installed, you should be able to build and run your code without any issues.